# How to wrapAll elements like this

Tags: jquery, dom, tags, word-wrap, wrapall

```
<div id="editor">
  text
  <div id="wrap"> <!-- here -->
    <img src="images/1.jpg"/>
  </div>
  text</p>
  <div id="wrap"> <!-- and here -->
    <img src="images/3.jpg"/>
    <img src="images/4.jpg"/>
    <img src="images/5.jpg"/>
    <img src="images/6.jpg"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you be more specific with your question? Wrap what? With what? What're the asterisks supposed to represent?

Comment: Assume for a moment you don't know what you're trying to accomplish and ask yourself - if I were someone else, would I understand this question? I know I have **NO IDEA** what you're trying to accomplish, what you've already tried and what *specifically* is not working

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I imagine you want to wrap groupings of `<img>` elements.

If so, do this:

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/patrick_dw/RXFVM/1/

```
$('#editor > img:not(img + img)').each(function() {
    $(this).nextUntil(':not(img)').andSelf().wrapAll('<div class="wrap"></div>');
});
```

- `'img:not(img + img)'`: get images that are not preceded by an image
- `.each()`: iterate over them
- `.nextUntil(':not(img)')`: get all next elements, as long as they are images
- `.andSelf()`: include the original image
- `.wrapAll('<div class="wrap"></div>')`: wrap the group

Note that I changed `id="wrap"` to `class="wrap"` since you can't reuse IDs on a page.

---

**EDIT:** Updated example link to use non-broken images.

Answer (score 0):

as i understand it you want to wrap images with jquery?

well it could look like this

```
$('img').wrap('<div id="wrap" />');
```

but really you have to be more precise if you want a better answer

Comment: I would like wrap images with jquery. Your example wraps all tags 'img'. but I need to wrap nearby tags between first img tag and last